# Visual Code Does not show any text, any suggestions?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, ide, text-editor

Good Morning everyone,

Hopefully some may help, I am new to visual code transferring over from thonny since im using C# I ust decided to start using visual code for both python and C#. When I code in Visual code and than close the program the text editor is blank as if nothing is there but I can still run the code as if there was. Does anyone happen to know where this problem stems from ir a solution?

Comment: You can add a screenshot of what is happening. This will help to understand the issue better.

Comment: I tried uploading a picture it says they are there when I added them, Im new to stack so not  sure how to make the images upload

Comment: Are you looking for intellisense as in visual studio

Comment: no, my code in general wont show like if I code a program close visual studio and then try to reopen that same file my text editor will be blank

Answer (score 0):

I had something like that with visual studio 2019.

When ever i was copying nuget packages to offline system.

Because winrar lock files when it copies visual studio couldn't access packages and couldn't rendered text.

Comment: did you end up fixing the issue?

Comment: Clean project - > restore packages fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, turns out I was using python and its not like C# so I had to open the .py file rather than the .sln file